# How to eval imacros to extract the id on the link?

Tags: imacros

Can you help me to extract the link then cut and retrieve some of the links in the form of id? I use several forms to be variables.

This is an example of a link and I want to take the id that is behind:

[image: example]

I use iMacros extension 8.9.7. This is my failed script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!!EXTRACT}}'.split('=')[0].trim();")

TAG POS=7 TYPE=IRON-ICON ATTR=ID:icon

TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Delete<SP>cellCtrl+M<SP>D
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#cell-{{!VAR2}}>PAPER-MATERIAL>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(6)>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#cell-{{!VAR2}}>PAPER-MATERIAL>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV>TEXTAREA" CHARS="good nigt"
```

Comment: (I removed 3 unnecessary Tags from your Post, only the 'imacros' Tag is relevant. And iMacros for FF v8.9.7 doesn't even support WebExtensions, it only works until FF56, recommended = FF55.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var u='{{!URLCURRENT}}'; var z=u.split('='); z[1];")
PROMPT ID:<SP>_{{!VAR2}}_
```

'z[0]' would return the part of the URL *before* the '=' sign, but you want the part which is *after* the '='... => 'z[1]'.